# zaproxy - API scan - how to point a specification file

Tags: zap

I have a specification file api.yaml 
As I understand I should use it like the following:

docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t api.yaml -f openapi

Should I put the file to some zap's directory?

Answer (score 2):

It's more like a docker question: The file needs to be accessible inside the container, so you'll need to mount a volume (e.g. the folder containing this file) - check out the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more details. Than, you can use the file using the mount point, for example:

`docker run -v /path/to/dir:/app/config -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t /app/config/api.yaml -f openapi`

Comment: thank you! I converted yaml spec to json and use it the following way:
`docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t apitest.json -f openapi `

Comment: There is a simpler docker solution than mounting `/etc/hosts': check out `--add-host`, see the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts). Besides that, I glad I was able to help! If you need more Zap help don't hesitate to reach out!